# Custom formatting a number column in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to format a decimal number column in Excel. In that number of decimal places should be minimum 0 and maximum 3.

Example:

The column will include the values like

> 1 
>   1.1 
>   1.12 
>   1.123

if i give the format code as 0.### It formats the column as follows

```
1.  
1.1 
1.12 
1.123
```

Note there is dot (.) in the first value. I want to remove that if there no decimal value. It should be 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Format as *General* and the **.** will not show for integer values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to format and run this short macro:

```
Sub Formatt()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    For Each r In rng
        If Right(r.Text, 1) = "." Then
            r.NumberFormat = "0"
        Else
            r.NumberFormat = "0.###"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular formatters don't do this well, what you can do is set the cell format to "text" and use =TRUNC(myCells,3) which then truncates and removes the decimal point. You'd need to hide your original values though as the formula works on an existing piece of data.

With a 3dp formatted input, you end up with.

```
12.000  | 12
12.100  | 12.1
12.110  | 12.11
12.111  | 12.111
```